# Why isn't my for-loop reassigning the data frame each time?

Tags: r

I am trying to filter through stocks from a list I have that don't fulfill a condition for a certain level of a positive trend present. I do this by requiring that the correlation cor( between time and stock price is at least .4, which means that there should be some level of positive trend.

I combined a for-loop with an if else statement, so that a correlation be examined for each stock in the list. My goal was that if the stock had the correlation > .4, it would remain in the list, else I would filter to a new data frame Stock_list and filter the data so that all the tickers would remain except for the rejected stock. However, what I am finding is that the filters are not being applied even if the else condition is met. In addition, the second part I added to the else conditon asking it to print "rejected" is operating successfully. I really am stuck as to why this problem is occurring. I am attaching a google.drive link to the CSV I'm using. It's small space-- only around 400 rows and 6 columns.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h4E6yg9U6oDeKUvsWhsQbFlxL3a6Fx-K/view?usp=sharing

I've tweaked around the code in all the ways I could imagine (which isn't many, but it has still taken quite some time), but I simply couldn't get it to work. I don't know why the filter is not being applied on each iteration of the loop. I'm using quantmod to pull historical stock data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(quantmod)


    Stocks <- read_csv("2018-19-KWHS-Approved-Securities.csv")
    Stocks <- filter(Stocks, EXCHANGE == "New York Stock Exchange" |  EXCHANGE == "NASDAQ Stock Market" | EXCHANGE == "NASDAQ - Industrial" | EXCHANGE == "NASDAQ Bank - Insurance" | EXCHANGE == "NYSE MKT LLC")
    Stocks <- read_csv("2018-19-KWHS-Approved-Securities.csv")
Stocks <- filter(Stocks, EXCHANGE == "New York Stock Exchange" |  EXCHANGE == "NASDAQ Stock Market" | EXCHANGE == "NASDAQ - Industrial" | EXCHANGE == "NASDAQ Bank - Insurance" | EXCHANGE == "NYSE MKT LLC")
Stocks <- filter(Stocks, TICKER != "AMCN" & TICKER != "CHKE" & TICKER != "DFBG" & TICKER != "GPIC" & TICKER != "NTRI" & TICKER != "BORN" & TICKER != "WMIH" & TICKER != "DWDP" & TICKER != "TAHO" & TICKER != "LABL" & TICKER != "SMI " & TICKER != "UTSI" & TICKER != "SMI")

    Stock_List <- Stocks


    Stock_filter <- function (na.rm = TRUE) {


      for (i in seq_along(Stocks$TICKER)){
    z <- getSymbols.yahoo(Stocks$TICKER[i],
                          globalenv(),
                          index.class = 'Date',
                          fr0m = "2018-01-01",
                          to = Sys.Date(), header = TRUE,
                          periodicity = "daily",
                          curl.options = list(),  auto.assign = FALSE)
    z <- data.frame(date=index(z), coredata(z))  
    names(z)[5]<- "Close_Price" 
    z <- transform(z, date = as.numeric(date))

    x <<- Stocks$TICKER[i]
    if (cor(z$Close_Price, z$date) > .4) {print(x)}
    else {Stock_List <<- Stocks %>% filter(TICKER != x)
    print("Rejected")}
    }}
```

I have adjusted the data set to be error free, but as previously mentioned, I am expecting the filter to happen on each iteration where the else condition is met, but that is simply not happening.

Answer (score 0):

When I add the following line of code, it runs, and gives results, with error... What are you getting?

```
Stock_filter(Stock_List)

WARNING: There have been significant changes to Yahoo Finance data.
Please see the Warning section of ‘?getSymbols.yahoo’ for details.

This message is shown once per session and may be disabled by setting
options("getSymbols.yahoo.warning"=FALSE).
[1] "Rejected"
[1] "Rejected"
[1] "AMZN"
[1] "Rejected"
[1] "AOBC"
[1] "APTV"
[1] "Rejected"
[1] "Rejected"
[1] "Rejected"
[1] "BBY"
```

... ...

```
[1] "MSFT"
[1] "NTES"
[1] "ORCL"
[1] "SINA"
[1] "Rejected"
[1] "Rejected"
[1] "Rejected"
[1] "Rejected"
Error in if (cor(z$Close_Price, z$date) > 0.4) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
UTSI contains missing values. Some functions will not work if objects contain missing values in the middle of the series. Consider using na.omit(), na.approx(), na.fill(), etc to remove or replace them. 
>
```

Comment: I added to the filters to help remove some faulty data. Can you try again but with the current code from the question?

Comment: @rocbak Please add "Stock_filter(Stock_List)" one line of code at the bottom of your program.  And Run it.  What is your expected result?  Stock_filter is a function, and it is only defined in the original code,  but never executed.  Which is why one line of code needs to be added to execute the filter.